# How to hide the javascript micro templating?

Tags: javascript, templates, external

is there a way to hide the javascript micro templating

like:

```
<script id="id" type="text/html"></script>
```

or at least putting all the template in a js file and call them somehow???

Answer (score 0):

Try loading them via AJAX instead, and store them in variables as strings. This way, you can load them on demand. Have a cache mechanism handy as well.